# too many sessions created by Spring MVC

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC, MySql and Tomcat 7.
Currently the application I'm developing can be accessed by 2 URLs namely IP:PORT/APP and www.app.com.

When accessing via www.app.com I see a session being created for every page/link that I open but it doesn't happen when I access via IP:PORT/APP.

I have a check for logged-in user in every page and due to too many sessions that check is failing and I'm being re-directed to my login page even after logging in.

Also when opening the www.app.com index page I see a jsessionid on the address bar and not when i open it via IP.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you are accessing the page via domain name (www.app.com), ***cookie support*** is not found and hence the ***url rewriting*** is being done (i.e. appending jsessionid at the end of the url). But this is not observed while accessing the same page via IP Address (IP:PORT/APP), meaning cookie support is enabled at this time.

You can check if you have enabled some ***security settings*** that is not allowing cookies.

Further to this, it seems that even url rewriting is not helping as sessions are being created for every request.

You can use some HTTP Interceptors to analyze the request being sent and response being received in each case. You can use ***Developer Tool*** in Chrome to inspect this. Load you page in Google Chrome, Right Click on Page and Click '***Inspect Element***'. Open the '***Network***' tab. Reload the page. You can now inspect the ***HTTP Request Headers*** sent and ***Response Headers*** received for each request. Analyze the difference between the request using IP Address and requests using Domain Name.

Also, share the ***architecture*** of the application and the ***environment*** where you are testing the application.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your response.
I did validate in google chrome as per your suggestion.
I noticed a few parameters missing in request :

- No cache-control in www.app.com
- No Cookie in www.app.com

Comment: I'm using Spring MVC for development with Tomcat 7 and Mysql deployed on a Linux server